# How to mount read/write with pmount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I use `pmount` to mount USBs as normal user. But how can I use pmount so I can write to the device too, instead of just read from it? I tried `pmount -w /dev/sdb1` but it doesn't work, `/media/sdb1` is still unwritable by anyone except by root. Filesystem of USB partition is `ext4`.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just use NTFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `-w` affects mount option (like in `mount -o rw …`). File and directory permissions and ownership are something completely different. You can be experiencing this: [*Different UID/GID when using an ext4 formatted USB drive with another computer*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38309/108618).

If `root` user can write to the filesystem, then it *is* mounted as writable, so `-w` *does* in fact work. The rest is just an ownership issue. You can "fix" it with `chown` (if you have `sudo` access etc.). Later on another OS you may have the same problem due to UIDs/GIDs not matching between systems, as explained under the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

`pmount` will not alter the mounted filesystem's permissions - thus you'll need to use `chown`, `chmod` or similar approach (as root) to change the owner/group/permissions of the root (or other relevant point) of the filesystem.

For example:

```
$ ls -dn mnt
drwxr-xr-x 3 0 0 1024 Dec 30 18:36 mnt
$ touch mnt/test
touch: cannot touch 'mnt/test': Permission denied
```

```
$ sudo chown $(id -nu): ./mnt
```

```
$ ls -dn mnt
drwxr-xr-x 3 1000 1000 1024 Dec 30 18:34 mnt
$ touch mnt/test
$ ls -ln mnt
total 12
drwx------ 2    0    0 12288 Dec 30 18:34 lost+found
-rw------- 1 1000 1000     0 Dec 30 18:36 test
```

This will persist across mounts... but be careful as the numeric UID/GID will need to line up on all systems that you use the filesystem on.

Comment: Is it possible to mount system as writable by user without root privileges?

Comment: That is a broken question. You need to change the root (or a subdirectory) of the filesystem such that your user has permission to write to it.

Comment: @Vuk Read: [*Possible to mount an ext4 partition image via FUSE?*](https://serverfault.com/q/403175) If you use NTFS, you will use FUSE as well.

Comment: If you're open to alternative filesystems, try NTFS / exFAT / FAT, and use the `-o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)` options.